# Which is more accurate JSON or sphericalutil.computedistancebetween in getting the distance between two address

Tags: android, json, google-maps, spherical-coordinate

I need to know the accurate distance of two locations (latlng). I did JSON and sphericalutil.computedistancebetween but their results are way too different. Like this instance, when I get the distance bet. two location in JSON the result is 9.8 km and in sphericalutil.computedistancebetween 9.18 km I know that spherical util results to meters I just converted it to KM. I'll be waiting for answers and please explain to me what is the difference of the two. Hoping for answers. Thank you so much.

Comment: What do you mean when you say `JSON`? What method/API are you using o get that measure?

Comment: I just use the DIRECTION_URL_API and my Google api key to get the object w/c is the distance from the JSON array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [Google Directions API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/) returns the route between two points, and thus, the distance returned takes into account the route returned (driving route for example).

The [SphericalUtil.computeDistanceBetween](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/SphericalUtil.html#computeDistanceBetween-LatLng-LatLng-) computes the distance between two points as the shortest distance on Earth between two `LatLng`s. This is, the sortest path (arc on the reference ellipsoid) between two points, not taking routes into account.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Now I know what to use.